# flutter video player ( media kit ) on windows 7

Tags: flutter, dart, desktop, video-player

I have been using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/media_kit), and it works perfectly fine on Windows 8, 10, and 11. However, on Windows 7, it only displays a black screen while the video's audio plays in the background. I don't have a video picture, and I'm not sure what to do to resolve this issue. If anyone has any insights, please guide me.

Thank you.